# Переходность глаголов

Tags: морфология

Ученику в четвертом классе задали такое упражнение: определить переходность глаголов в словосочетаниях "сыплются лепестки", "доносятся звуки", "царапаются кошки". В данном случае словосочетания являются скорее предложениями (мы имеем подлежащее и сказуемое), поэтому глаголы можно считать непереходными. Но в школе работу забраковали, написав, что существительные в этих словосочетаниях-предложениях стоят не в именительном падеже, а в винительном. Прав ли учитель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, задание не четко понято? Вряд ли учитель не в курсе, что при наличии частицы "СЯ" глагол является непереходным. Скорее всего, это продвинутый учитель, который хотел показать детям разницу между  пассивным и возвратным залогом у глаголов.

Частица СЯ может являться:

1) показателем ПАССИВНОГО залога, который противопоставляется активному залогу: дерево сыплет  лепестки (В.п.)- лепестки сыплются; ветер доносит звуки (В.п.) - звуки доносятся.

2) показателем ВОЗВРАТНОГО залога: кошки царапаются (и ещё как!) - субъект совершает активное действие, направленное на себя, прямой объект при этом отсутствует (в данном случае действие или состояние характерно для данного субъекта).

Answer (score 1):

Он с ума сошел. Возвратные глаголы вообще не могут быть переходными, а приведенные "словосочетания" - не что иное, как нераспространенные двусоставные предложения. Пишите кляузу.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала давайте разберемся. Не все глаголы в винительным падеже являются переходными. При переходных глаголах действие переходит на объект. Ср.: ***простоять час (в очереди) или жить неделю (на море),*** где глаголы не являются переходными, хотя после них и стоят существительные в винительном падеже без предлога: Следует также отметить, что возвратные глаголы ( глаголы с суффиксом,постфиксом  ***-ся(-сь) ,*** относятся к  непереходным.

И такие педагоги преподают.

Comment: Обратите внимание на класс. Четвертый! Раньше в программе начальной школы ничего подобного не было. К сожалению, не все учителя  умеют самостоятельно пополнять свои знания. Честно говоря, не понимаю, зачем нужно знать о переходности ученику 4 класса. Замечательная программа Бабайцевой и в 5-9 классах обходится без этого термина.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, наличие постфикса -ся - показатель непереходности. Но такие сочетания называются словосочетаниями на основе сочинительной связи. Такая же история с однородными членами.